# The topic is/are smart homes

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

What is correct?

1.) The topic is smart homes.

2.) The topic are smart homes.

Regarding 1.) It sounds wrong for me, but in my opinion grammatically correct.
Regarding 2.) It sound right, but grammatically incorrect.

Thanks!

Comment: There's only one topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English, the verb must agree with the subject, not the object. So the first one is, as you've surmised, grammatically correct:

> The topic is smart homes.

The subject and the object do not need to agree in number. But if it sounds odd to you, you can reword the sentence to avoid the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify terminology: "smart homes" in the sentence I quoted is the subject complement.

Comment: Please check likely candidates for duplicates before adding repeat answers.